# Differentiable function has measurable derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

Let $f:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Is it true that $f'$ is measurable?

If so, is this also true if $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere?

Sorry for lack of effort but I don't have any clue about the answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here's a key observation: Assume that $f$ is differentiable and define

$$f_n(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
  \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n} & \text{if } 0 \leq x+1/n \leq T \\
  0 & \text{else.}
\end{array}\right.$$

Then, each $f_n$ is measurable and $f_n \rightarrow f'$.

Comment: This needs a small adjustment for $x$ close to $T$, since $f(x+1/n)$ does not need to be defined.

Comment: Yes, take $n(f(x+\frac{T-x}{nT})-f(x-\frac{x}{nT}))$ instead.

Comment: Mark, the comment is serious. You need a sequence of functions defined on all of $[0,T]$, not just on some interval that approaches $[0,T]$. What you wrote does not work.

Comment: @Andres: Well, $f'_-(T)$ exists, so we can easily extend $f$ to a differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @TonyK There is a variety of ways the argument can be fixed/completed/understood, thus the "small adjustment" comment.

Comment: I think there is a typo... $f_n\rightarrow f'$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Thanks! How'd I miss that for 758 days? :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure : I do not usually edit answers.. But this one was very old one and i thought i can do.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Absolutely - thanks again!

Comment: @MarkMcClure : I was just wondering how do we define differentiability of $f$ at $b$ for a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.. Is it sufficient to see existence of its left derivative?

Comment: Why should the limit of measurable functions be measurable?

Comment: @JohnCataldo If $f_n$ is a squence of functions on a measure space, then the set $\{x:f_n(x)\to x\}$ is measurable. The result follows from there.