# Is the assumption of Lebesgue integrability necessary here?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Question $10.34$, Chapter $10$, in Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis" ($2^{\text{nd}}$ edition):

> If $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable on an open interval $I$ and if $f^{\prime}(x)$ exists almost everywhere on $I$, prove that $f^{\prime}$ is measurable on $I$.

In view of the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639674/differentiable-function-has-measurable-derivative) (as modified by Hagen von Eitzen's comment and adapted appropriately for open intervals), is the assumption that $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable (as opposed to just measurable) necessary to solve question $10.34$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I would not say so. Let $A$ be the subset of $I$ where $f'$ exists. By definition, $A$ is the difference of $I$ and a set of measure zero, so it is measurable. Now set $Df_n(x) := \frac{f(x+n^{-1})-f(x)}{n^{-1}}$ for $x \in A$. Clearly, $Df_n$ are measurable and also note that $x \mapsto \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Df_n(x)$ is measurable ($a \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary):
$$
(\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Df_n)^{-1}([-\infty, a]) = \bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N}}  \underbrace{Df_n^{-1} [-\infty, a)}_{\text{measurable}}
$$
Analogously, $\sup Df_n$ is also measurable (for Details see Evans, Gariepy - Measure theory...). Then
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} Df_n = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{n \geq k} Df_n
$$
is measurable and hence
$$
f'(x) =  \liminf_{n \rightarrow\infty}\chi_A(x) Df_n(x)
$$
is measurable.

Integrability was not needed here. It is enough to just demand measurability.

Comment: Some possible typos/mistakes: $a \gt 0$ instead of $b \gt 0$, $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} Df_{n} = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{n \geq k} Df_{n}$ instead of  $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} f_{n} = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{n \geq k} f_{n}$, and  $n$ instead of $n^{-1}$ in the denominator of the definition of $Df_{n}$.

Comment: Thank you, will correct

Comment: Are $n^{-1}$ (in the denominator of the definition of $Df_n$) and $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{n \geq k} f_{n}$ correct in your answer, given that you didn't change them after my comment?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The reason is, that in the "usual" difference quotient you have $h$ in the denominator and $h \rightarrow 0$. In this formulation I replaced by $h$ by $n^{-1}$ (where the latter also goes to $0$)

Comment: Also note my recent edit: I pulled the limit to the outside, because we can not say whether $\liminf Df_n$ exists when $x \notin A$. Now, the expression vanishes when $x \notin A$.

Comment: Ok, I see. But what about $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{n \geq k} f_n$? Why isn't this $\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \inf_{n \geq k} Df_n$?

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that one